# A question about the continuity of a linear mapping between two normed spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

The question comes from the Ex.5.16 of Rudin's Real and complex analysis, the original problem looks like this:

[image: The problem]

However, in my proof, I didn't use the fact that $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, instead I only assume they are arbitrary normed space. I don't know if my proof is wrong, or this theorem can be generalized to arbitrary two normed spaces.

Here is my proof:

Let $\Lambda$ be arbitrary mapping from $X \rightarrow Y$, which $X,Y$ are two normed spaces.

---

Let $G = \{(x, \Lambda x): x \in X\}$, then we claims $G$ is a normed space with norm

$$
||(x, \Lambda x)|| = ||x|| + ||\Lambda x||
$$

To prove this:

(1)

$$
||(x_1 + x_2, \Lambda x_1 + \Lambda x_2)|| = ||x_1 + x_2|| + ||\Lambda x_1 + \Lambda x_2||
$$

$$
\leq ||x_1|| + ||x_3|| + ||\Lambda x_1|| + ||\Lambda x_2||
$$

(2)

$$
||\alpha (x, \Lambda x)|| = \alpha ||(x, \Lambda x)||
$$

(3)

$$
||(x, \Lambda x)|| = ||x|| + ||\Lambda x|| = 0
$$

$$
\Rightarrow x = \Lambda x  = 0
$$

---

Consider the mapping $\phi:G \rightarrow X$ , $\phi((x, \Lambda x)) =x$.

It's obvious that $\phi$ is 121 and onto.

To show $\phi$ is continuous:

Let $\epsilon > 0$, we can have

$$
||x_1 - x_2|| \leq ||x_1 - x_2|| + ||\Lambda x_1 - \Lambda x_2|| = ||(x_1, \Lambda x_1) - (x_2, \Lambda x_2)|| < \epsilon
$$

Thus $\phi:G \rightarrow X$ is continuous, and thus $\phi^{-1}:X \rightarrow G$ is continuous.

---

Let $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $||x_1 - x_2|| < \delta$, we have

$$
||x_1 - x_2|| + ||\Lambda x_1 - \Lambda x_2|| < \epsilon
$$

$$
||\Lambda x_1 - \Lambda x_2|| < \epsilon - \delta < \epsilon
$$
for all $(x_1, \Lambda x_1), (x_2, \Lambda x_2) \in G$

Therefore, we can say for any $x_n \rightarrow x$, we have $\lim \Lambda x_n \cap G[1] = \Lambda x$, which means $\Lambda: X \rightarrow G[1]$ is continuous and onto.

(Here $\lim \Lambda x_n$ represents the set of all limit points of \Lambda x_n, and $G[1]$ represents $\{\Lambda x : x \in X\}$)

---

To make the statement clear:

$\Lambda:X \rightarrow Y$ is not continuous at $x$ iff there are sequences $a_n, b_n \rightarrow x$ with $\lim \Lambda a_n \not = \lim \Lambda b_n$

---

Suppose we have $a_n \rightarrow p$, $b_n \rightarrow p$ for $a_n,b_n,p \in X$ and $\lim \Lambda a_n \in G[1]$ and $\lim \Lambda b_n \not \in G[1]$.

---

When $y_n = \lim \Lambda b_n$ exists, then we have $\lim \Lambda b_n = \Lambda \lim b_n = \lim \Lambda a_n$, and this is impossible.

Thus, we must have $\lim ||\Lambda b_n|| \rightarrow \infty$.

Consider

$$
\Lambda_1: X \rightarrow Y
$$

$$
\Lambda_2: X \rightarrow G[1]
$$

We know $\Lambda_2$ is continuous, thus $\Lambda_2$ is bounded, and $||\Lambda_2b_n|| \leq ||\Lambda_2|| \cdot ||b_n||$

Therefore $||b_n|| \rightarrow \infty$, but this contradicts with $b_n \rightarrow p$

Therefore $\Lambda:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous

Done.

(I am confused. I didn't use the fact that $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, so I thought I might be wrong, but I can't find error in my proof, can anyone help me?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'$\phi:G \rightarrow X$ is continuous, and thus $\phi^{-1}:X \rightarrow G$ is continuous': This is false without completeness. For example, consider the identity map from $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm  to $C[0,1]$ with the $L^{1}$ norm. This is continuous but its inverse  is not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

When I study elementary topology, I remember it says if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and one-to-one and onto, then $f^{-1}:Y \rightarrow X$ is also continuous. So I am confused why it can't be applied here, since I showed that $\phi$ is also one-to-one and onto.

Comment: You might have seen that result for functions from $\mathbb R$ to itself. It is certainly false in general. @Leaves

Comment: Thanks. I checked my textbook, and I find it's only true for 121 mapping from a compact metric space onto a metric space. Thanks for your help!